# Java ProcessBuilder Error When Space(s) In Path

Tags: java, processbuilder, spaces

So I spent *half a day* trying to get this to work with no positive result. I am using a **Java ProcessBuilder** to execute some .exe file with a couple of arguments, but the file-path contain space(s) and somehow I can't get it to work properly. I have checked a number of other SO posts and implemented solutions like surround code with escaped quotes and splitting it up in command and arguments etc. My code is below:

```
try {
    ProcessBuilder pBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(
        // Main Command.
        "C:\\namewith space\\database\\postgres_db\\bin\\pg_ctl.exe",
        // Command Parameters.
        "start",
        "-D C:\\namewith space\\database\\database",  
        /*The quotes in the next argument are necessary, the -o stands for 'options' and everything between the quotes are the actual database parameters which to start the Database with.*/
        "-o \"-p 15000\"",
        "-l C:\\namewith space\\database\\postgres_db\\bin\\postgres_log.txt");

    File log = new File("\"C:\\folder\\log.txt\"");
    pBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    pBuilder.redirectOutput(Redirect.appendTo(log));
    Process p = pBuilder.start();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception Occurred: " + ex);
    }
```

I have tried so far:

- Surrounding and not surrounding each/any of the paths in the above code with escaped quotes just in case that matters (something tells me it does...).
- Using the `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("full command with/without any/all escaped quotes");` method, but when searching on SO I found out everyone is saying you should use the ProcessBuilder instead.
- Adding parts of the above code together in different ways in the ProcessBuiler's first command String, like `"\"C:\\namewith space\\database\\postgres_db\\bin\\pg_ctl.exe\" start"`
- The files are 100% located at the given paths, I checked this by hand and by pasting the paths in the File Explorer over 10 times.
- Splitting up the command into setting the working directory of the command to C:\namewith space\ and then adding the args without that part.

The error (via the `System.out.println("Exception Occurred: " + ex);` ) I keep getting is: **java.io.IOException: Cannot run program *"C:\namewith space\database\postgres_db\bin\pg_ctl.exe"*: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.**

Please let me know if you need any extra parts/code and I will do my best to provide it in detail.

Comment: I don't suppose fixing the directory name or creating a symlink to that path without a space are viable options? I wouldn't be surprised if those are your only choices. That error message looks like it's coming from the OS, not from Java.

Comment: Changing the dirName isn't an option. However if I copy/paste the exact same full statement including quotes in a command prompt it works. Works if you put it in a .bat file too. Please tell me more about what a syslink is.

Comment: A [symlink](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+symlink) is a file that is just a pointer to another location on disk.

Comment: Also, please update your question with the full stack trace from the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try to break the problem down.

First just read the absolute path shown in the IOException into a File object and call the exists() method to check that the file really exists and the JVM has access to it.

If that didn't work, fix your path or the access permissions. If the file really exists and you can access it then create the ProcessBuilder **without any parameters**, just with absolute path to your exe.

You shouldn't get the IOException now. **Then add the parameters one by one**. If you find one that breaks the thing, then fix the parameter (maybe the double quotes are missing) and go onto the next until you finish.

Comment: Created a new File object with the path to the file I'm trying to access. myFile.exists() returns true. So the program has access to it which is a good thing. Then adding the EXACT same path (with or without extra escaped quotes around the path) returns an IOException. [Screenshot of the output](http://i.imgur.com/Un4XNWF.png).

Comment: If you call the getAbsolutePath() method on the file object and you use the returned string as the command, does that work?

Comment: That's actually exactly what I did :/ Created a new `File` object with that path, then checked if the file is accessible by the code with `myFile.exists()` and then created the pBuilder like `new ProcessBuilder(myFile.getAbsolutPath())` without any other arguments.

Comment: I just tried this and it worked:

`ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\my dir with spaces\\whatever\\my.exe"); pb.start()`

Comment: In that case, compare (byte by byte, if necessary) the contents of that string vs. the result of `myFile.getAbsolutePath()` and you'll find your error. My guess is there's some unusual character being passed to the `File` object which the `File` API is able to handle, but Windows is not.

Comment: [The error](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc956689.aspx) you get is apparently returned by Windows because the path contains invalid characters.You could rename by hand all the subdirectories in the path to your exe, typing (not copy-pasting) the same name as they had before. This would avoid the directory names don't contain invalid characters. Then, you could re-type by hand the path you have hardcoded in your java code. This would avoid special characters in your java code.